# Applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem to $\int_{C_R} z^n \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

First, [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem):

If $f$ is a continuous function on $U$ admitting a holomorphic primitive $g$, and $\gamma$ is a closed path in $U$, then
\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma f = 0
\end{equation}

---

When applying this theorem to $z^n$ over some circle $C_R$ of radius $R$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_R} z^n dz = \cases{0, & $n \ne -1$ \\ 2\pi i, & $n=-1$}
\end{equation}
(Note, we are allowed to apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem to $f(z)=z^n$ since a primitive $g$, namely $g(z)=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$, exists).

My question is, why isn't $\int_{C_R} z^n \ dz$ identically zero? Why doesn't Cauchy's Theorem hold for the case $n=-1$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize $C_R$ by $z=R e^{i \phi}$ for $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi)$.  Then

$$\oint_{C_R} dz \, z^{-1} = i R \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} R^{-1} e^{-i \phi} = i 2 \pi$$

Comment: Ah, perfect. I came to the same answer but was confused why the answer wasn't zero. Thank you for your help, Ron!

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem now.

Note that when $n=-1$, the primitive $g(z)=\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$ is undefined, and thus the theorem doesn't hold. I wish I had seen this faster...

Comment: In fact, there is no holomorphic primitive for any negative value of $n$, because the primitive must be holomorphic **on and inside** the contour.  For example, if $n=-2$ then $z^{-2}$ has a primitive $-z^{-1}$, but this is not valid when $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a homology version of Cauchy's Theorem.

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ Suppose $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{C}$, $\Gamma$ is a formal sum of closed curves. Suppose that $\text{Ind}(\Gamma,a)=0$ for all $a\in 
\mathbf{C}\backslash V$. Suppose that $f\in H(V)$. Then
$$
\int_{\Gamma}f(w)dw=0.
$$

$\textbf{Remark.}$ It is  OK to apply this theorem for $n\ge 0$. When $n=-1$, $f(z)=1/z$ has a singularity at $z=0$. We can not apply this theorem. We could either do computation directly, or apply the [Residue Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).